# Serving Django application with nginx at domain subpath

Tags: django, nginx

I'm using **nginx** to serve my SPA front end and my **django** back end (a REST api).

My django backend runs at `http://127.0.0.1:8000` with gunicorn.
The IP of my server is `http://X.X.X.X/`

I want to serve my front end from `http://X.X.X.X/` and my backend from `http://X.X.X.X/api/`.

So far, my nginx configuration file for my front end looks like this.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/frontend/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/frontend/error.log;


    location /api/ {
       proxy_pass http://goa:8000/api/;
       proxy_redirect http://goa:8000/api/ http://$host/api/;
       proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /api;
    }

    location / {
       alias   /var/www/html/goa/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I tried to follow this [post](http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2011/Sep/15/hosting-django-under-different-locations).

The problem now is that the django routing always route to `/api/` but my routes don't know about this prefix. So if I go to `/api/admin/` django will be handling the request but won't find `/api/admin/` because it only knows about `/admin/`.

I know I could rewrite my routes in Django itself but I'd like to keep everything related to route redirection in nginx configuration.

Comment: What happens when you change proxy_pass to: `http://goa:8000/`? I'm not really that knowledgable about nginx though. Also, try setting `proxy_redirect` to `off`.

Comment: Internal server error.... :(

Comment: Where? Nginx or Django?

Comment: Gunicorn, who is not happy about the fact that SCRIPT_NAME is set with no `api` in the url.

Comment: Why are you setting `SCRIPT_NAME`?

Comment: because Django needs to prefix internal `urls` with `api`, such as `admin` or the request `http://X.X.X.X/admin/` will be passed to nginx